# JavaScript regex for PHP block <?php echo $imagePath; ?>

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regex for the below PHP block and want to replace it with the actual image path.

```
<?php echo $imagePath; ?>
```

I have tried

```
str.replace(/<\?[=|php]?[\s\S]*?\?>/g, 'images/dir1/');
```

but it is replacing all other PHP blocks of the page also. I want a regex which replaces a particular PHP block.

Comment: you should not operate `php` code from `js` code. This `<?php echo $imagePath; ?>` should be rendered, then you may do replacement

Comment: Why not use PHP?

Comment: I know we should not. But I am using ckEditor to edit php files and there i want actual path to show images. ckEditor can't render php tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following *regex* ...

```
<\?php\secho\s\$imagePath;\s\?>
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DFc1aP/1)**

**JavaScript**

```js
var phpblock = '<?php echo $imagePath; ?>';
var result = phpblock.replace(/<\?php\secho\s\$imagePath;\s\?>/g, 'images/dir1/');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. It worked. Earlier i tried <\?php\secho \$imagePath;\s\?>. 
and missed \s between echo and imagePath. Silly.. :P

Comment: @AbhiAndhariya You're Welcome :-)